# How to load routing network data in MMPK?

Tags: android, sdk, runtime, arcgis

I now have a mobile map package (.mmpk) on hand and I want to perform routing in an app that I mm going to make. However, I don't know how to load the transportation network inside the mmpk. Can anyone give me some advice on that? Thanks.

P.S. the app is going to be made with the use of Android Studio and I am using Java to do it.

P.S.S. the routing network data is inside a geodatabase

Here is the code, please take a look:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.esri.arcgisruntime.loadable.LoadStatus;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.MobileMapPackage;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView;

import java.io.File;

public class ActivityElderly extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "MMPK";
private static final String FILE_EXTENSION = ".mmpk";
private static File extStorDir;
private static String extSDCardDirName;
private static String filename;
private static String mmpkFilePath;
private MapView mMapView;
private MobileMapPackage mapPackage;

String[] reqPermission = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
private int requestCode = 2;

private static String createMobileMapPackageFilePath(){
    return extStorDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + extSDCardDirName + File.separator + filename + FILE_EXTENSION;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from new_activity.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.map_elderly);
    // get sdcard resource name
    extStorDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    // get the directory
    extSDCardDirName = this.getResources().getString(R.string.config_data_sdcard_offline_dir);
    // get mobile map package filename
    filename = this.getResources().getString(R.string.config_mmpk_name);
    // create the full path to the mobile map package file
    mmpkFilePath = createMobileMapPackageFilePath();

    // retrieve the MapView from layout
    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ActivityElderly.this, reqPermission[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        loadMobileMapPackage(mmpkFilePath);
    }else{
        // request permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityElderly.this, reqPermission, requestCode);
    }
}

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults){
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            loadMobileMapPackage(mmpkFilePath);
        }else{
            // report to user that permission was denied
            Toast.makeText(ActivityElderly.this, getResources().getString(R.string.location_permission_denied),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
private void loadMobileMapPackage(String mmpkFile){
    //[DocRef: Name=Open Mobile Map Package-android, Category=Work with maps, Topic=Create an offline map]
    // create the mobile map package
    mapPackage = new MobileMapPackage(mmpkFile);
    // load the mobile map package asynchronously
    mapPackage.loadAsync();

    // add done listener which will invoke when mobile map package has loaded
    mapPackage.addDoneLoadingListener(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // check load status and that the mobile map package has maps
            if(mapPackage.getLoadStatus() == LoadStatus.LOADED && mapPackage.getMaps().size() > 0){
                // add the map from the mobile map package to the MapView
                mMapView.setMap(mapPackage.getMaps().get(0));
            }else{
                // Log an issue if the mobile map package fails to load
                Log.e(TAG, mapPackage.getLoadError().getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    //[DocRef: END]
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.resume();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to prepare the package then lease take a look at the tool that does just that http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-mobile-map-package.htm#GUID-9116AC0F-08E1-4B55-965D-123F01262A53

If you are looking how to create a RouteTask then please look at the documentation https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/guide/find-a-route.htm

If you are looking for a way to load the network data from already prepared offline package then please look at the sample on github https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-android/tree/master/java/mobile-map-search-and-route

In short you just take any map that contains network dataset and use it in you RouteTask.

```
ArcGISMap map = mMobileMapPackage.getMaps().get(0);
//if map contains transport network setup route task
if (map.getTransportationNetworks().size() > 0) {
    mRouteTask = new RouteTask(this, map.getTransportationNetworks().get(0));
}
```